# xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Tags: python, xml

I am a newbie to Python. I am trying to write a script to modify some data in XML files that I need to use for my testing purposes. I did see a few folks ask the same question, but I was not able to figure out from the answers there what I was doing wrong. I appreciate the help. Here is a sample XML that I am picking up to modify. Thanks for the help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Parent>
  <FlexIDResponseEx xmlns="http://WWW.YYYY.com/SsIkkk">
    <response>
      <Header>
        <Status>0</Status>
      </Header>
      <Result>
        <InputEcho>
          <Name>
            <First>John</First>
            <Last>Doe</Last>
          </Name>
          <Address>
            <StreetAddress1>XX XXX XX XXXXX</StreetAddress1>
            <City>XXXXXX</City>
            <State>XX</State>
            <Zip5>XXXXX</Zip5>
          </Address>
          <Age>0</Age>
          <SSN>XXXXXX</SSN>
          <HomePhone>XXXXXXXXX</HomePhone>
        </InputEcho>
        <UniqueId>XXXXX</UniqueId>
        <NameAddressPhone>
          <Summary>1</Summary>
          <Type>P</Type>
          <Status>C</Status>
        </NameAddressPhone>
        <VerifiedElementSummary>
          <DOB>XXXXXXXX</DOB>
          <DOBMatchLevel>8</DOBMatchLevel>
        </VerifiedElementSummary>
        <ValidElementSummary>
          <SSNValid>0</SSNValid>
          <SSNDeceased>0</SSNDeceased>
          <PassportValid>0</PassportValid>
          <AddressPOBox>0</AddressPOBox>
          <AddressCMRA>1</AddressCMRA>
          <SSNFoundForLexID>0</SSNFoundForLexID>
        </ValidElementSummary>
        <NameAddressSSNSummary>2</NameAddressSSNSummary>
        <ComprehensiveVerification>
          <ComprehensiveVerificationIndex>50</ComprehensiveVerificationIndex>
          <RiskIndicators>
            <RiskIndicator>
              <RiskCode>A</RiskCode>
              <Description>Null</Description>
              <Sequence>1</Sequence>
            </RiskIndicator>
            <RiskIndicator>
              <RiskCode>MS</RiskCode>
              <Description>XXXXXX</Description>
              <Sequence>2</Sequence>
            </RiskIndicator>
            <RiskIndicator>
              <RiskCode>25</RiskCode>
              <Description>XXXXX</Description>
              <Sequence>3</Sequence>
            </RiskIndicator>
            <RiskIndicator>
              <RiskCode>74</RiskCode>
              <Description>The input phone number is associated with a different name and address</Description>
              <Sequence>4</Sequence>
            </RiskIndicator>
            <RiskIndicator>
              <RiskCode>52</RiskCode>
              <Description>The input first name is not associated with input SSN</Description>
              <Sequence>5</Sequence>
            </RiskIndicator>
          </RiskIndicators>
        </ComprehensiveVerification>
        <CustomComprehensiveVerification>
          <ComprehensiveVerificationIndex>0</ComprehensiveVerificationIndex>
        </CustomComprehensiveVerification>
        <InstantIDVersion>1</InstantIDVersion>
      </Result>
    </response>
  </FlexIDResponseEx>
</Parent>
```

Here is my python script I am trying to write

```
import os
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

fileList = []
p = os.popen('ls *JJ*',"r")

while 1:
    line = p.readline()
    if not line: break
    fileList.append(line)

j = len(fileList)+1


for i in range(1, j):
    lnFile = open(fileList[i], "rb")
    tree = parse(lnFile)
    first = tree.find('First')
    first.text = 'YYYY'
    Last = tree.find('Last')
    Last.text = 'ZZZZ'
    tree.write(fileList[i])
    lnFile.close()
```

Here is the stack Trace

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Users/parser/parse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/parser/pare.py", line 17, in <module>
    tree = parse(lnFile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1958, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 913, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 211, in parseFile
    parser.Parse("", True)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

P.S I am using PyCharm CE

Comment: No, there is no space at the beginning.

Comment: In the error, `parser.Parse("", True)` is a bit cryptic but its what you get when you try to parse an empty file. Print out file names before you parse and check to see if it has the content you think it should have.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers:
It may be, that the provided file is not existent for the XML interpreter (programming error). It would throw an error and stop working. I had a *similar* issue.

Step 1:
I opened a shell script `postfile.sh` and ran a line straight inside my IDE like `curl -X POST http://172.20.1.2:8080/pyserver/parse -d @$1`

The error returned was: `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: no element found: line 1, column 0`, which is equal to the OP's mentioned error.

My error was to run the `curl` command directly without any parameter.

Step 2 (Solution):
Add the file's name and then everything works fine. The correct command was:
`./postfile.sh demofile.txt`

The xml interpreter got something to munch on and this error is gone.